# Problema en consola al escuchar cambios con nodemon al usar .writeFile

Tags: nodejs, npm

Tengo un problema al guardar los cambios corriendo `nodemon` , la consola se me refresca todo el tiempo ,
esto sucede a partir de ejecutar `fs.writeFile` dejo el fragmento de codigo

```
fs.writeFile('notas.json','prueba', (err) => {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log('Archivo actualizado Satisfactoriamente');
  });
```

### consideraciones

- el archivo se actualiza ok , no hay error en consola pero se refresca el mensaje de exito todo el tiempo
- corro nodemon con `npx nodemon -q`
- tambien pasa corriendo nodemon con `npm start`
- no encontre respuesta en la documentacion de nodempon ni en el modulo nativo fs de node
  -si salgo de la escucha con nodemon y ejecuto simplemente `node main` funciona ok

Answer (score 0):

Lo que hace nodemon es básicamente que cuando tú editas el archivo que se está ejecutando y lo guardas, todo el proceso vuelve a ser leído

¿Por qué no lo integras dentro de una función todo ese proceso?